# Set SPWorkflowStatus to InProgress in SPWorkflowEventReceiver OnCompleted Event

Tags: list, event-receivers

I created a WorkflowCompleted Event Receiver to perform some operations when status is 16 (Approved).  This article helped me with this: [Workflow Event Receiver](http://blog.symprogress.com/2011/09/sp-2010-get-workflow-status-workflowcompleted-event/).  The custom code executes when Workflow has completed and is Approved.  Is it possible to change Workflow status back to InProgress (i.e. 2) in this same event receiver?  My understanding is this type of event receiver runs asynchronously (so after the event has completed).

I tried to change status back to 2 and call Update() on the item, but it sets the workflow status on the list item to blank.  I need it to show InProgress.  Is what I am looking to do possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that because the workflow is no longer running, changing the value of the Workflow Status field essentially returns a null value (2 on a null workflow is null, not "In Progress"). In any case, changing it to "In Progress" without actually restarting the workflow would provide incorrect information to the users.

Can you restart the workflow from your event receiver?

Comment: Would restarting the workflow recreate the tasks assigned to the approvers?

Comment: It depends on the workflow, but probably. What exactly is the business case here?

Comment: When workflow completes in Approved status I call another system to execute certain functions. I then create a task in the Tasks list. I would then like to set workflow status back in inprogress.  When that other system function completes I will mark the task as complete and mark workflow status as approved.

Comment: Hmm; I would suggest using ANOTHER column to indicate the status of the item itself: since your business process itself involved more than just the workflow. Once the workflow starts, you can set the field to In Progress, and once you kick off the second phase it would remain in progress (or you could set it to something like 'In Progress - Step 2'), and then finally you would set it to complete when the final task is marked complete.